# Reasons for PHP's popen command to fail

Tags: php, email, pipe

I have a batch email process that sends about 30,000 email messages. I have ran into a strange problem where it gets to about 85% completion of the process and then the email start failing with the message `Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail` I am using a library called PHPMailer 1.73 and the relevant code where the error message comes from is

```
if(!@$mail = popen($sendmail, "w"))
{
    $this->SetError($this->Lang("execute") . $this->Sendmail);
    return false;
}
```

The value of `$sendmail` is of the form: `/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f support1@example.com -t`

I have `set_time_limit(0);` so the script will not timeout.

Is there anyway to figure out why all of a sudden popen() starts failing? Could the OS be running out of file descriptors or some other limit being reached?

How should I resolve this? Should I have it sleep and then retry the popen() several times before failing?

**Update**: Thanks to the suggestion of Marko to check out `proc_open()` I found on the [proc_open documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php#95207) a comment that if it returns `FALSE` it probably means that you ran out of file descriptors or you are out of memory. I found that my process was taking `20G` of memory. But how could it take that much memory if `memory_limit` is set at `64M`? Well, it seems that running external programs with `exec()`, `popen()` or `proc_open()` do NOT count against PHP's memory limit. See this SO question for more info on that, [Debugging memory usage in mod_php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604039/debugging-memory-usage-in-mod-php). I'm still not sure how this is happening but I suspect some sort of memory leak.

In summary, `popen()` and `proc_open()` can return `FALSE` if you are out of file descriptors or out of memory.

Comment: Is your server configured with a maximum amount of smtp relays per hour/day? What is your script execution timeout set to?

Comment: Could be running out of PIDs as well. older unix boxes (linux especially) had a ceiling of 2^16 pids. 30,000 emails sounds like it could be getting close to that, with regular system processes included. Though, I'd hate to see what the system load would b elike with 30,000+ sendmail instances chugging away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use proc_open instead. It is slightly more complex to use, but gives you access to stdout and stderr. The messages on this two pipes will save you a lot of debugging time.

How to use, just read the examples and comments in the PHP documentation.