# What are common causes of PHP memory leaks?

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding cause of memory leaks in large PHP stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849549/finding-cause-of-memory-leaks-in-large-php-stacks)

What are common causes of PHP memory leaks? I'm looking for things that are commonly done by unsuspecting PHP programmers that cause memory leaks.

Comment: like [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+memory+leak)?

Comment: You might try giving us a few more specifics about your question. The normal things might include firing off a thread and forgetting about it or the like, but if you have a specific instance in which you are trying to hunt down a leak you might let us know the circumstances.

Comment: Maybe the fact that it's PHP? ;)

Comment: Please be aware that leaking memory in a PHP script is *usually* not a big deal, as most scripts have a very short lifetime.  You only really need to worry about this for long-running PHP processes, such as daemons.  You should also read about [PHP 5.3's new garbage collection mechanism](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php), which can take care of circular references, a common source of "leaked" memory.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of leaks is circular references. However, as of PHP 5.3, those are now detected and taken care of.

So now the only causes of "leaks" should be:

- A bug with PHP (I don't know of any offhand; check the active bug reports.)
- Building large (for instance) arrays or strings that you never "free" (i.e., You continue to reference them)

So in short, there shouldn't be much of a problem if you remember to stop referencing data you no longer need.