# Memory leak in php zend functions

Tags: php, memory-leaks

I am getting memory leaks in the php code. When I ran the code with debug enabled php 5.3.10, I am seeing memory leaks in zend functions. As far as I know, zend use its own garbage collector to clean up the allocated memory. Could you suggest what can be done in such a case?

.../php-5.3.10/Zend/zend_objects.c(32) :  Freeing 0x0229FD20 (64 bytes), script=static_cl_put.php
.../php-5.3.10/Zend/zend_alloc.c(2454) : Actual location (location was relayed)
Last leak repeated 9998 times

[Wed Apr 11 10:06:52 2012]  Script:  'static_cl_put.php'
.../php-5.3.10/Zend/zend_objects.c(31) :  Freeing 0x0229FE50 (72 bytes), script=static_cl_put.php
Last leak repeated 9998 times

Thanks,
Sunanda

Comment: Are you talking about Zend Framework or the Zend Engine? They are quite different.

Comment: Need to see the PHP code you are using.

Comment: I am talking about Zend Framework.

Comment: See if my answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11157739/881736

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

to your php script who use that zend component so you will be able to override the initial .ini limitation.

You may also need after that to edit:

```
ini_set('max_input_time', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');
```