# Symfony, memory limit

Tags: php, symfony

i got this error when using php bin/console server:run , and the server won't start.
 php bin/console server:run

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\Users\Messkan\Desktop\businessplace\vendor\jms\serializer-bundle\JMSSerializerBundle.php on line 43

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\Users\Messkan\Desktop\businessplace\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryExce
ption.php on line 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Diagnosing Memory Leaks - Allowed memory size of # bytes exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849549/diagnosing-memory-leaks-allowed-memory-size-of-bytes-exhausted)

Comment: 2 MB is extremely low. You're going to want to increase your memory limit.

Comment: See also, this setting: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: how to increase it using hctaccess ? i use php 7?

Answer (score 5):

use this command to increase memory allocated:
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/console server:run

or increase this option in php.ini in your php folder.

Comment: Setting `memory_limit` to `-1` is considered to be a bad practice though.

Comment: the problem is that i can't touch the php.ini in the server, and that doesn't work on .htaccess

Comment: -1 can be changed with any value followed by a measure unit: 128M or 1G... if you cant touch php.ini and you have access to the server panel there will be a php configuration page to adjust the memory if not you should call the server administrator to make the appropriate changes

Comment: is this in your computer: C:\Users\Messkan\Desktop\businessplace

Comment: if so, you can run a php local server instead of symfony server:run using "php -S localhost:8888" then access your app with "localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/"

Answer (score 2):

You probably have either:

1. An entity related to thousands of other entities, and by the time you get to a very high amount of records being serialized, memory maxs out, or...
2. A circular reference in one of your entities

Increasing the memory limit may fix it if is not a circular reference, but that's not a proper fix. You have to be efficient. Control your hydration and references. Also, IMO, JMS Srializer is not the best tool for a presentation layer. Try `league/fractal`.

Comment: how to increase the memor_limit using htacess ? I use php 7

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase `memory_limit` value in `php.ini` file for the php version you are using (e.g. php7.0).

So navigate to your `php.ini` file there, find `memory_limit` line in this file & try to set value to `1G` or `2G` (depending on the app size, - how much you really need). Save changes & restart your server (apache/nginx), and try once again.

Comment: how can i do that using htacess?,

Comment: Try adding new line `php_value memory_limit 1G` to your `.htaccess` file